# "Insert into where" statement error

Tags: mysql

I have an mysql query that keeps coming back with an error

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' iOS= 0, Android= 0, sport IN (football,tennis,' at line 2
```

The whole query is

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE iOS = 0
    , android = 0
    , sport IN (football,tennis,golf)
```

(iOS and android columns are boolean values and sport is a `VARCHAR`)

The query is meant to get all entries where the iOS/ android columns are 0 and the sports column value is either football or tennis or golf.

Where's the mistake?  Thanks for any help

Comment: Use `AND` instead of the commas to build your condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More onditions are included using `AND` or `OR`.

Literal Strings are delimited using quotes:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE iOS = 0
AND android = 0
AND sport IN ('football', 'tennis', 'golf')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your  `WHERE` statement is wrong. You have to add the `AND` condition between clauses.

```
WHERE iOS = 0 AND android = 0 AND sport IN ('football', 'tennis', 'golf')
```

Comment: When I change it to "and"  I get the error Error: Unknown column 'football' in 'where clause'

Comment: one problem solved, there are more.. quote your strings.

Comment: add quotation marks to the values inside the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

just type **and** insted of ,(comma) and write sports name in single quote

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `iOS` = 0 and android = 0 and (sport IN ('football','tennis','golf'))
```